# Edirol UA-25 driver on Windows 8 Preview

Tags: drivers, windows-8-preview, sound-card

I've installed Windows 8 developer preview on a laptop and everything is working apart from my external sound card.

The sound card in question is [this one](http://www.roland.com/products/en/UA-25/), and I've tried downloading and installing the Window 7 drivers from [here](http://www.roland.com/support/article/?q=downloads&p=UA-25&id=16192819) but no joy so far.

As per the instructions I remove the USB cable from the port. I then run setup.exe and (which I have set to run in Windows 7 compatibility mode).  It starts doing it's stuff then says "Please insert the USB cable and wait"......that's where things stop!  Nothing happens.  I don't even here the "ding-dong" of the USB device being recoginised.

Obviously I realise that the drivers are for windows 7 and not 8, but was hoping that someone would be able to crowbar it to work!!!

Any tips appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See if [this thread](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=56548) is relevant, regarding the Advanced switch at the back of the unit.

Comment: Have you tried calling Rolland? I didn't see any forums supplied by them or I'd say use that, but if you contact the company you might talk them into putting you through to whoever writes their drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quotes in the FAQ for the product:

> The driver came with the Windows 7 have some limitation, use the Windows 7 Compatibility driver instead.

This makes me believe the Compatibilty driver (with possibly reduced features) available for Windows 7 ([32bit](http://www.roland.com/products/en/_support/dld.cfm?PRODUCT=UA%2D25&iRcId=16192818&dsp=1) and [64bit](http://www.roland.com/support/article/?q=downloads&p=UA%2D25&id=16192818)) does not have all the fullfeatures. Can you verify you are attempting to use the correct one?

> For the products introduced after Windows 7, please refer to each product information page on the Roland.com website.

[All downloads for UA-25 here](http://www.roland.com/support/article/index.cfm?q=downloads&p=UA-25), I imagine when/if a Windows 8 driver is available it will be listed. [There is no mention at all of Windows 8 compatibility anywhere else on their website](http://search.roland.com/en_all/search.x?q=%22Windows+8%22&ie=UTF-8&page=1).

Comment: It sounds like the device doesn't even have real Windows 7 specfic drivers only "compatability drivers" my guess he will see neither Windows 7 drivers nor Windows 8 drivers for this device.

Comment: Alas, I think you are right.  Thanks for taking the time to have a look around.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 7 x64 driver doesn't install in Windows 8 Release Preview. However, the Vista x64 driver does and appears to work well if installed manually through Control Panel. No issues as of yet. Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this question now, it seems Roland have now released a [Windows 8 driver](http://www.roland.com/support/article/?q=downloads&p=UA%2D25&id=62483076) for the UA-25, so hopefully all should now be well.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall all drivers. Download the Vista 64bit or 32bit Driver depending on your system from rolands website. Make sure you unpack (unzip) it into a folder on your desktop. Plug in the UA25 and ignore all messages. Go to control panel/device manager where you will see UA25 in the list. Click and update drivers by navigating to the previously folder on your desktop. Wait for all drivers to install.

Comment: The question refers to windows 8 not windows 10.